# In this Symfony core class, what is the fully qualified class name of the token that's being returned?

Tags: php, symfony, token

I am building some extra unit tests for a Symfony 2.7 application. In order to do that, I need to mock the output of a `getToken()` method that the application is using.

The getToken method is defined within this short class:

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

/**
 * TokenStorage contains a TokenInterface.
 *
 * It gives access to the token representing the current user authentication.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 * @author Johannes M. Schmitt <schmittjoh@gmail.com>
 */
class TokenStorage implements TokenStorageInterface
{
    private $token;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getToken()
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setToken(TokenInterface $token = null)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }
}
```

Now I just need to figure out what type of Token is being returned by the method. Since this is a core part of Symfony, I figured I would ask before spending an afternoon debugging: Does anyone know the full name of the token class off the top of their head?

Comment: Out of the getToken method?  It's going to be the same as is passed into setToken (and thus listed in the 'use' lines. It's an interface though, and so could be one of a few different concrete classes. Depend on getting something that matches the interface though.  You can also 'mock' the interface itself, rather than anything more specific.

Comment: Thanks, Alister.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your object into `get_class()`:

```
$fullClassName = get_class($this->token);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php